# How to integrate FB iOS SDK 3.1.1 with App Requests

Tags: facebook, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-app-requests

I've been looking for a solid answer that explains how to keep 3.1.1 in my project but also implementing the app request dialog. What I've read says I need to import Facebook.h and call it like `[self.facebook dialog:@"apprequests" andParams:params andDelegate:self];` but when I import Facebook.h and comment out `#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>` I then get conflicts with

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                              allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                             FBSessionState state,
                                                             NSError *error) {
                                             [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                                 state:state
                                                                 error:error];
                                         }];
```

Could someone guide me through how I maintain my 3.1.1 SDK but also add apprequests? My goal is to select FB users then send an app request to join my app.

Thanks,

Wes

Comment: Hi, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-3.1-to-3.2/ the new version (3.2) of Facebook SDK has supported for this.